# R command to test if data in a range

Tags: r, range

```
output<-which(data1>160 & data2<1.5)
```

will select all data where values in data1 is greater than 160 and values in data2 is less than 1.5.

How can I modify above command to return output where data1 can be in a range of 150 to 160 and data2 can be in between  1.4 to 1.5

```
output<-which(150<data1>160 & 1.4<data2<1.5)

## -Error: unexpected '>' in.
```

What is the correct syntax.

Comment: `which(data1 < 150 & data1>160 & data2 > 1.4 & data2<1.5)` ?

Comment: this will work, But I have several such conditions to combine, wondering is there a easier way of setting range.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that only works for integer values (150.1 would not work)

Comment: `which((data1 %in% 150:160) & (data2 %in% seq(1.4, 1.5, by =.1)))` @SeñorO thanks for the comment, fixed

Comment: @DavidArenburg Still fails if data1 is 150.1. Or if data2 is 1.42

Comment: @SeñorO, yeah, but he didn't provide a reproducible example, so I'll let him break his head if it won't work

Comment: @DavidArenburg he specifically stated "data2 can be in between 1.4 to 1.5"

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
150 < data1 & data1 < 160 & 1.4 < data2 & data2 < 1.5)
```

If you are specifying a range of values, you need to logical statements for each range (since a range has two limits)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the recommended approach, it's easy to read and may save you some typing... You can use `range` as a replacement function like so:

```
"range<-" <- function(x, `*tmp*`, value){
    `*tmp*` <- x
    x <-  x[x > min(value)]
    x <-  x[x < max(value)]
}
d1 <- seq(140, 160)
d2 <- seq(100, 200)/100
range(d1) <- c(150, 160)
range(d2) <- c(1.4, 1.5)
c(d1, d2)
```